# how to create dynamic text boxes in Access vba

Tags: ms-access

I want to create 200 text boxes in Access form with a `for` loop and call them s1, s2, s3, etc.

I don't want to create them by myself in the form design. Can I have a code example?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It sounds like a bad design for any number of reasons, but it's also something that you don't want to do in a production app, either.

Answer (score 5):

I agree this is not a very good idea however in the interests of giving people enough rope to hang themselves with……….

```
Public Function Make_controls(iLoops As Integer)
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmYour_form", acDesign
Dim x As Integer
Dim ctrl As Control

For x = 1 To iLoops
    Set ctrl = CreateControl("frmYour_form ", acTextBox, acDetail, , "", 0 + (x * 300), 0, 300, 240)
    ctrl.ControlName = "txtDynamic_control_" & x

    DoCmd.Save acForm, " frmYour_form "
Next x
DoCmd.Close acForm, " frmYour_form ", acSaveYes

End Function
```