# Generating an arbitrary number of textboxes on an Access form

Tags: json, vba, ms-access

Essentially I am looking to make a JSON Editor in MS Access that:

1. Reads JSON data stored as a single string in a table, parses it (I have that mostly figured out with the VBA-JSON library),
2. Displays all JSON key-item pairs as label-textbox controls in a form (or textbox-textbox controls so the key can be edited as well)
3. Allows the user to edit those key-item pairs through the generated controls
4. Converts the control data back into a string and updates the table

I want to make this because the relational database model works very well for our use case except for one area; recording the specs for hardware with very disparate criteria. Most of the criteria do not need to be operated on, they just need to be stored for posterity and passed en-masse to a report at some point.

The issue I am having is with item #2. Each JSON record will have a different number of key-item pairs, and potentially entirely different keys (with a few exceptions like ProductName or Manufacturer), so I need to be able to generate the relevant controls for each individual JSON string that is parsed.

I've looked at some related questions, seems that [generating the textboxes with a For loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180570/how-to-create-dynamic-text-boxes-in-access-vba) is not recommended. [Another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33430307/how-to-create-a-continuous-form-in-access-vba-with-variable-number-of-text-boxes?rq=1) suggested creating as many textboxes as I think I would ever need, and hiding those not in use. That seems like it might work but doesn't seem very elegant.

I'm not looking to convert this JSON data into a table as that defeats the purpose of storing it as JSON in the first place, but would it make sense to create a sort of 'dynamic table' that is used for storing the active parsed JSON entry so it can be viewed as a datasheet? Are there performance issues with that?

I'm open to that option but would prefer to keep it as a textbox form for ergonomics.

Comment: _creating as many textboxes as I think I would ever need, and hiding those not in use_ - is the way to go. You can stack them in one spot, then move them around as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your table has a JSON-encoded field, containing one level of key/value pairs, with no deeper structure, and no defined schema to enforce keys and data types.

In this case, I would convert the JSON to a work table for the purpose of editing. The VBA-JSON converter will return a Dictionary object. Loop through the dictionary keys to build the work table. This can be presented to the user as a Subform.

When done, loop through the work table records to build a new dictionary object, then use VBA-JSON to convert it to a JSON string.

You can use an actual Access local work table, or (much cooler!) you could use a disconnected ADODB recordset. This would be an editable Recordset entirely in memory. But that's another topic.

Comment: My JSON does have some deeper structure, the occasional object with subvalues like "Dimensions" : { "Height": , "Width": , "Depth": } but I suppose I could flatten that if I had to. If I found I needed more structure though, how would one go about converting a multiple-level JSON to a table? Some sort of tag to record the parent object of each key/value? If you could also help me figure out rebuilding the dictionary object from records and point me to some more info on ADODB recordsets that would be great thanks!